# Python Try with some Additional Logic

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to make 'try' only work under one condition:

```
try:
    print "Downloading URL: ", url
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
except:
    message = "No record retrieved."
    print message
    return None
```

I do not want the above code to work if the kwarg nodownload is True.

So I have tried the following:

```
try:
    if nodownload:
        print "Not downloading file!"
        time.sleep(6)
        raise
    print "Downloading URL: ", url
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
except:
    message = "No record retrieved."
    print message
    return None
```

The above always downloads no matter if the --nd argument is passed in the command line. The below always skips the file rather the argument is passed or not.

```
    if not nodownload:
        print "Not downloading file!"
        time.sleep(6)
        raise
    print "Downloading URL: ", url
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
except:
    message = "No record retrieved."
    print message
    return None
```

No download is input at the command line:

```
parser.add_argument('--nodownload', dest='nodownload', action='store_true',
                    help='This doesn't work for some reason')
```

Comment: `if not nodownload: `?

Comment: I tried something along those lines and it failed. I will post updated code after lunch. Thanks.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. It is not clear where the `nodownload` variable is from.

Comment: where is `nodownload`??

Comment: Something like adding a `if 'nodownload' in kwargs and not kwargs['nodownload']: raise MyException` in the try block...? Or put the try block inside a `if 'nodownload' not in kwargs or not kwargs['nodownload']:`. Anyway you should take care of bare `except` clauses, they may hide you exceptions you might want to know about.

Comment: No download is passed from the command line:     nodownload = kwargs.get('nodownload', False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raise` to cause an exception when you need to, thus making the `try` fail.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, one can raise an exception.

Apart from using predefined exceptions, you may also use your own:

```
class BadFriend(Exception):
    pass


class VirtualFriend(Exception):
    pass


class DeadFriend(Exception):
    pass


try:
    name = raw_input("Tell me name of your friend: ")
    if name in ["Elvis"]:
        raise DeadFriend()
    if name in ["Drunkie", "Monkey"]:
        raise BadFriend()
    if name in ["ET"]:
        raise VirtualFriend()
    print("It is nice, you have such a good friend.")
except BadFriend:
    print("Better avoid bad friends.")
except VirtualFriend:
    print("Whend did you shake hands with him last time?")
except DeadFriend:
    print("I am very sorry to tell you, that...")
```

You can even pass some data via raised exception, but be careful not to abuse it too far (if
standard structures are working, use simpler ones).